# Cannot convert character column positionally to datetime using strptime()

Tags: r

I have a data frame (d) where the second column is a character col named **event.date**. A sample value in this column is "2012-07-23 00:00:00" (datetime data)
I want to convert the second column to a datetime. I tried two things:

**1)** d[,2] <- strptime(d[,2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

 **Result**: Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 2, value = list(sec = c(0, 0, 0,  :
  provided 9 variables to replace 1 variables. 

 **head(d)** shows event.date having a value of 0 (not good)

**2)** d$event.date <- strptime(d$event.date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

 Works OK ... I need to be able to convert a datetime column using **positional** column notation.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks

**str(d)** looks like:

'data.frame':   826 obs. of  6 variables:
 
$ event.id        : int  229162 129163 392564 392665 398466 355167 326168 397269 399170 399171 ...
 
$ event.date      : chr  "2012-07-23 00:00:00" "2012-07-23 00:00:00" "2012-07-23 00:00:00" "2012-07-23 00:00:00" ...
 
$ severity        : Factor w/ 6 levels "Clear","Critical",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 
$ message.type    : Factor w/ 37 levels "AC Power Lost",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 15 ...
 
$ message         : chr  "The user  has logged into XX0852-036128 from 10.211.221.118." "The user has successfully logged 
 
$ entity.name     : chr  "XX0852-036633" "XX0902-037744" "XX0902-037A55" "XX0902-037D70" ...

Comment: `d$event.date <- as.Date(d$event.date, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` or just `as.Date(d$event.date)` if you don't care about the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
> d <- data.frame(foo = rbinom(2, 10, .3), event.date = c("1990-01-10 04:30:13", "1987-03-08 02:12:14"), tt = rpois(2, 42), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> d
  foo          event.date tt
1   4 1990-01-10 04:30:13 37
2   3 1987-03-08 02:12:14 41
> d[[2]] <- strptime(d[[2]], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
> d
  foo          event.date tt
1   4 1990-01-10 04:30:13 37
2   3 1987-03-08 02:12:14 41
> sapply(d, class)
$foo
[1] "integer"

$event.date
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 

$tt
[1] "integer"
```

I don't really know what the difference is between `d[,2]`, `d[2]` and `d[[2]]` is in this example. I just know from experience that this does the trick here. You could poke around the source code of `[.data.frame`, `[[.data.frame`, `[<-.data.frame` and `[[<-.data.frame`.

Comment: That works ... thanks a lot. Can you explain why it worked. I.e., why d[[2]] correctly refers to the second col where d[,2] doesn't.

Comment: What does `str(d)` look like? Maybe edit your answer to include this output.

Comment: Thanks Jake. I'll spend some time figuring it out when I get the chance.